# Linux, C - Is it possible to link against 2 dynamic librraries with equal functions names

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries, linker-flags

I am forced to link two version of the same third party dynamic library (Linux .so, C language) into the same executable to support old and new functionality in the same process. Having two executables or remote services are undesirable.

I made the assumption that this must be a doable task. I tried to experiment with the naive approach of creating 2 proxy dynamic libraries each  linked against one of the real libraries and have function renamed.
Unfortunately, this attempt failed – both new functions call the same target function.
I still want to believe that the problem is in the lack of my knowledge as there are plenty of compiler and linker ( gcc and ld) options.

I will appreciate any help. I also look forward to using dlopen/dlsym, but first want to check if the original approach can work.

Here is the sample code

```
/* ./old/b.c */

#include <stdio.h>
int b (int i)
{
    printf("module OLD %d\n",i);
    return 0;
}

/* ./old/Makefile */

libold.so: b.c
    gcc -c -g b.c
    gcc -shared b.o -o $@

/* ./new/b.c */

#include <stdio.h>
int b (int i)
{
    printf("module new %d\n",i);
    return 0;
}

/* ./new/Makefile */

libnew.so: b.c
    gcc -c -g b.c
    gcc -shared b.o -o $@

/* ./a1.c */

#include <stdio.h>
int b(int);
void call_new(void)
{
    printf("will call new 1\n");
    b(1);
    printf("called new 1\n");
}

/* ./a2.c */

#include <stdio.h>
int b(int);
void call_old(void)
{
    printf("will call old 2\n");
    b(2);
    printf("called old 2\n");
}

/* ./main.c */

#include <stdio.h>
int call_new(void);
int call_old(void);
int main()
{
   call_new();
   call_old();
   return 0;
}

/* ./Makefile */

.PHONY: DEPSNEW DEPSOLD clean
main: liba1.so liba2.so main.c
    gcc -c main.c
    gcc -o main main.o -rdynamic -Wl,-rpath=new -Wl,-rpath=old -L . -la1  -la2
DEPSNEW:
    make -C new
DEPSOLD:
    make -C old    
    
liba1.so: DEPSNEW a1.c
    gcc -c -fpic a1.c
    gcc -shared a1.o -L new -lnew -o liba1.so

liba2.so: DEPSOLD a2.c
    gcc -c -fpic a2.c
    gcc -shared a2.o -L old -lold -o liba2.so
clean:
    find -name "*.so" -o -name "*.o" -o -name main | xargs -r rm
    

/* ./run.sh */

#/bin/sh 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=new:old:. main
```

The result is not that I want - function from "new" library is called twice

```
will call new 1
module new 1
called new 1
will call old 2
module new 2
called old 2
```

Comment: `dlopen` with `RTLD_LOCAL` is your best chance.

Comment: I think this is not possible by changing anything in the programming or build process. However it might be possible by either kicking the libraries out of the way, creating a linker script instead and aliasing the symbols. Or by just having the linker script be at a preferable location. I'm not entirely sure this will fit your needs, but it might be worth looking at.

Comment: Rename names to something meaningful?

Comment: The *kind* of thing you describe is achievable, but the specific combination you are trying to form might or might not be.  Doing this sort of thing is not easy.  Before you go further, I recommend that you study Ulrich Drepper's paper [*How to Write Shared Libraries*](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/a/1/e/dsohowto.pdf), which covers dynamic linking (among other topics) in good detail.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can not control the automatic loading of the dynamic library in order to assure which library will be loaded for the depending libraries. What you can do, is to use one of the libraries (the new one) for the dynamic linker and to link the second library manually as follows:

Add function to dynamically load and link the function from the library.

**a2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
static int (*old_b)(int);

void init_old(void) {
   void* lib=dlopen("./old/libold.so", RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_LAZY);
   old_b=dlsym(lib,"b");
}

void call_old(void)
{
    printf("will call old 2\n");
    old_b(2);
    printf("called old 2\n");
}
```

call the initialization function

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void init_old(void);
int call_new(void);
int call_old(void);
int main()
{
   init_old();
   call_new();
   call_old();
   return 0;
}
```

Modify the linker options to add the dynamic loading library `-ldl`

```
liba2.so: DEPSOLD a2.c
    gcc -c -fpic a2.c
    gcc -shared a2.o -L old -lold -ldl -o liba2.so
```

After this modification

```
~$  ./run.sh
will call new 1
module new 1
called new 1
will call old 2
module OLD 2
called old 2
```

Comment: Are all libraries suitable for loading in this way?
We tried this approach and one of the functions produced an error indication that means 'library not initialized'. Unfortunately, I cannot provide the library. I can only tell that I suspect it is poorly written

Comment: Any dynamic library (shared library) can be loaded in this way. The error means that you need to call additional functions in the library before using it. Usually, library exports initialization function which is called automatically from `dlopen()`, but many libraries will have additional protocols of initialization before use, especially if they are `plug-in` type of libraries. Here is more on the [standard initialization](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/miscellaneous.html#INIT-AND-CLEANUP). Unfortunately, without having the library is difficult for me to tell what is going on.

Comment: We managed to load and use both libraries simultaneously with dlopen. 
I wish to thank everybody for  help.